# Multiple DbCon Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, unit-of-work

```
namespace MyMain.Controllers
{
    public class Home
    {
       **//Open First Db Connection Here**
        public MyDbConEntities db = new MyDbConEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var user = db.User.FirstOrDefault();

            **//Open second Db Connection Here**

            using (var myTask = new MyTask1())
            {
                myTask.Execute(user.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace MyMain.Task
{
    private MyDbConEntities db = new MyDbConEntities();
    public class MyTask1 : IDisposible
    {
        private int Id;
        public MyTask1(int id)
        {
            db = new MyDbConEntities();
            Id = id;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            **//Open thidr Db Connection Here**
            using (var mySubTask = new MySubTask1())
            {
                mySubTask.Execute(Id);
            }

            db.UserDetails.FirsOrDefault(x => x.UserId = Id)
        }

        public Dispose()
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Hi friends, My question about that Open Multiple DbCon at the same time.

At the above code, I tried to show my idea. My purpose that, at each seperate Task Class open DbCon. But sometimes, I call one task from another task class.

So sometimes, at the same time a few dbCon can be opened for a short time. I dont want to send MyMain/Home Class db object as instance for task classess.  I thought error handling case. For example, when error occured at MySubTask1
(if I use db object as instance , dbCon can be closed and whole system can be fail.

So I try to implement this... What do you think about my ideas?

Can you give me a clue?. This method can be a problem on server for huge Database and users.

What about to use UnitOfWork with this methods?

Comment: you can with UnitOfWork handel your DbContext for better performance .implementation Context per request pattern

Comment: What did you say as clearly? I understand that unit of work can be used. Also my ideas will not create a problem when I publish as release on the server? So I can open multiple dbcon at the same time. Isn't it? Thanks alot for your interest.

Comment: why you want do this work ?

Comment: For learning?  I want to seperate  task for Solid prencibles. Also, via this method, I can perform task as sepertly. I can call this task in N tier arch... And I can say lots of benefit. May I am wrong, Can you help me?

Comment: Also my another purposr is, each task  can have own DbCon

Comment: Yes , I Use UnitOfWork In My Projects. if you want I Explain  UnitOfWork in an Answer

Comment: Thansk a lot, My question is that, UnitOf Work; can help me to solve this problem? At each task method, I want to use DbCon. Sometimes, One task can call another this means that  two or a few DbCon can opened at the same time  on Same Database. Can unit of work solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Design N-Tir Application Based on EF Not common that in each class and method which We Want use it create instans of DbContext.

In this way, 
Ability to perform different tasks during a transaction is destroyed.

for solve this Problem Use **Context Per Request** Pattern or UnitOfWork,
By doing this Share Instans Of Context in different Layers.

**The importance of Model Unit of work and share it during a call**

**A)** Better performance

**B)** Concurrency issues

**C)** 
The correct use of transactions